# How to find out frequencies of elements in dataset?

Tags: r

I have a dataset. The view of the dataset is attached.

[image]

I want to find out the frequencies of unique elements in particular column say X.V4.y. This contain many values like Jazz Club some 50 60 times, Railway station say 30 time etc etc.

I want the following output.

```
    Jazz club  60
    Railway Station 30
    etc  40
    etc  40
```

Similarly, I want the same thing with X.V.1 who have only values of X.V4.Y = "Jazz Club" and similarly for all the vales in X.V4.y.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the `dput` of your data. You might want to look into `?table`

Comment: You can use sort(table(dataset$variable), decreasing=T)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table` is the function you are looking for.

```
table(myDF$X.V4.y)
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for expect one thing. I am looking for table in ascending order. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I. Data frame created

```
 A <- data.frame(a=c("Tree","Tree","Plant","Tree","Letter","Letter"),b=c("K","K","L","K","K","K"))
 A
 #        a b
 # 1   Tree K
 # 2   Tree K
 # 3  Plant L
 # 4   Tree K
 # 5 Letter K
 # 6 Letter K
```

II. Frequency of entries in Columns

```
 table(A$a)
 # Letter  Plant   Tree 
 #      2      1      3 
 table(A$b)
 # K L 
 # 5 1
```

III. Frequency of entries in ascending order

```
 sort(table(A$a),decreasing=F)
 # Plant Letter   Tree 
 #     1      2      3 
 sort(table(A$b),decreasing=F)
 # L K 
 # 1 5
```

IV. Barplot of `A$a`

```
barplot(table(A$a),col=c("red","blue","green"),main="Barplot of A$a")
```

V. Barplot of Top two in the ascending table of `A$a`

```
BP <- sort(table(A$a),decreasing=F)
BP
# Plant Letter   Tree 
#     1      2      3 

BP[1:2]
# Plant Letter 
#     1      2 

barplot(BP[1:2],main="Top Two of Ascending table",col=c("red","orange"))
```

Comment: Can I use table function to display it data in ascending order?

Comment: Yes, you can do `sort(table(A$a),decreasing=F)`

Comment: You want to print all data, or just that column in ascending order or you want data to be sorted in ascending order of that column?

Comment: I need the output of `table(A$a)` in frequency ascending order.

Comment: Yes so the above command I mentioned would do that. Keep `decreasing=F` in that command.

Comment: I also want to make the histogram of top ten from the results of table(A$a). What is the best way to do that in r?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117612/discussion-between-sowmya-s-manian-and-hassan-saqib).